# Problemas con los Import y Export en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-import

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto para practicar todo lo que aprendí de JavaScript y estoy modularizando mi código para que sea más legible.

El problema es el siguiente, al momento de querer importar una constante, donde guardo algunos botones de una calculadora que estoy haciendo, me sale un error al llamarla a otro archivo que sería *Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'tipButtons' before initialization*.

Podría resolverlo de otra manera pero, me gustaría saber realmente a qué se debe este error para el día de mañana, si es que me vuelve a suceder, saber cuál es el problema.

Les dejo el link a mi repositorio para que lo puedan ver si quieren.

La constante a exportar es la que dice const tipButtons = [button5, button10, button15, button25, button50]; dentro de index.js

Y la importo dentro de buttonsStates.js (raramente en este archivo si me deja utilizar sin problema) y en value.js (es aquí donde no me deja utilizarla).

Les agradezco de antemano.

[Repositorio de mi proyecto en GitHub](https://github.com/Calvarenga96/splitter-calculator)

Comment: ¿Podrías subir el código aquí en vez de hacernos visitar el repo de Github? Es más fácil para nosotros proponerte una solución y más fácil para los que vengan después a revisar el problema.

Comment: Pensé en subir, solamente que creo que como son varios archivos, creí iban a necesitar leer los demás documentos para entender mejor e iba a perder mucha legibilidad si copiaba y pegaba todo en la caja de preguntas. Por ese motivo decidí dejar directamente el enlace.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema es que tienes **imports** circulares.

En **index.js** estas importando **values.js** y en **values.js** estas importando **index.js**

Normalmente se soluciona refactorizando el código. Mas info: https://medium.com/content-uneditable/circular-dependencies-in-javascript-a-k-a-coding-is-not-a-rock-paper-scissors-game-9c2a9eccd4bc

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ahora me pondré a leer y tratar de solucionar con tu solución.